# Mockito object mock changing to null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock the following function:

```
// Class ObjClass
public void updateColumn(long id, MyObj myObj, String errorLog) throws Exception {
        try {
            MyObj2 obj2 = entityManager.find(MyObj2.class, id);
            obj2.setStatus(myObj);
            obj2.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            obj2.setErrorLog(errorLog);
            entityManager.persist(obj2);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //some stuff...
        }
    }
```

My test class code looks like this:

```
@Mock

private EntityManager entityManager;

@InjectMocks
private ObjClass objClass;

@Mock
private MyObj2 myObj2;

Mockito.when(entityManager.find(MyObj2.class, id)).thenReturn(myObj2);
    ObjClass.updateColumn(id, myObj.SUCCESS, null);
```

Here, I am getting a null when the test code runs through and reaches the line `MyObj2 obj2 = entityManager.find(MyObj2.class, id);`

obj2 is null here, however, while debugging, before my test method reached this class, obj2 had the mocked value from test class code `@Mock private MyObj2 myObj2;`

Can someone suggest what may be wrong? Using Mockito.

Also, I want to mock the setters in the **updateColumn** method and verify those. Can someone help with those as well?

Comment: What is the value of `id`? Does it change? It would be could if you could rewrite your example so it contains the minimal executable program to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have just replicated your test and obj2 was not null. So I have to agree that the value of id inside updateColumn is most likely not the same as was used for the mock function. Maybe for now, change your mock function to Mockito.when(entityManager.find(eq(MyObj2.class), anyLong())) and see if that causes the test to work.